# What is the easiest way to see which CUDA kernels/code are ran?

Tags: pytorch

Is there a way to, while running a Torch module / forward function, see what CUDA code is generated and ran ?
I'm running on Windows so no torch.compile, wondering maybe I can somehow use NSight Compute for that ? Or maybe there's a debug option in Pytorch to display which CUDA kernels (.cu) are selected, fused (I guess?) and ran ?
If it's only possible via torch.compile/fx Graphs, that's still fine, I can try that on my Linux box.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I think nvprof.exe is what I've been looking for, it gives the names of the kernels.